# load() multiple elements from url into an array jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, get, loading

I'm far from an expert on JS and I need some help with loading multiple elements' content from other pages of the same domain. I have this now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div.container').each(function(){
    var link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('params');
    for(i=1; i<4; i++){
      var row = $('<tr />').addClass('param_' + i).html('<td class="val" />');
      table.append(row);
    };
    $(this).append(table);
    $(this).find('tr.param_1 td.val').load(link + ' #content1');
    $(this).find('tr.param_2 td.val').load(link + ' #content2');
    $(this).find('tr.param_3 td.val').load(link + ' #content3');
  });
});
```

It works, but as you can see there are multiple div containers on current page and each 'div.container' needs to get multiple elements placed in it from their respective urls. I would like to scan the url only once and get all the elements' content into an array, so that it doesn't load every page multiple times, as it increases loading time too much.

Or maybe you have other suggestions on doing it. But keep in mind that I have only some understanding of jQuery, nothing else. All the answers I found were very vague.

Thanks in advance. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think , you have to use local storage .

below code may helped you .

```
$(this).find('td[id^="tr_id_"]').each(function(key,val){
    if (localStorage.getItem("tr_id_"+key) === null) {
         /// Populate the data in td elements via local storage .
        document.getElementById("tr_id_"+key).innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("tr_id_"+key);

    }else{

         $(this).find('tr#tr_id_'+key).load(link);
          /// Store the data in local storage . 
         var html_content = document.getElementById("tr_id_"+key).innerHTML;
   localStorage.setItem("tr_id_"+key,html_content);

    }
});
```